# What to do with a question that was based on a wrong assumptions?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-delete

I asked a question based on a wrong assumption. As it later turned out, my problem had nothing to do with what was assumed in the question. The answer to my question, however, is based on that wrong assumption.
My question now would be what to do with that question? As it cannot be altered without rendering the answers useless and wrong, should it be deleted?

It'm talking about this question:
 [How would I address QWidgets Ui when working with namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449333/how-would-i-address-qwidgets-ui-when-working-with-namespaces)

Comment: Would the question and answer be useful to others? In that case let it stay

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just leave the question.  If it's a valid question with an answer that may well be helpful to future visitors then the site is serving it's purpose.  It may not have helped *you*, but that doesn't mean it can't help *anyone else*.  In any case, the post has an answer with a positive score, so you couldn't delete it even if you wanted to.

If you still have a problem that you need help with then just ask a new question, given that trying to edit this one would be too much of a radical change that would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable thing to do, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The long term objective of a stack exchange question is to be useful to a number of people (only the first of which is the question author). It is from that perspective that you should make your decision, I think this question could be of use to others and so should stay.

The question is of course moot as you can't delete it anyway as it has upvoted answers